# Find a particular solution of $\frac{1}{xD+1} (x^{-1}) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm familiar with sums where the coefficient of D is a constant. I don't know how to solve ones like these, and I don't know what these sums are called.
Can someone please suggest any reference material (available online) for this?

Comment: Symbolab.com is good

Comment: What's the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\frac{1}{xD+1}\frac1x$. Then
$$ (xD+1)y=\frac1x$$
or
$$ xy'+y=\frac1x.$$
From this you can get
$$ (xy)'=\frac1x$$
which can be solved easily.